# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Hangs with "Waiting for Operation to Complete" Message

Tags: visual-studio

I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 hanging with a "Waiting for Operation to Complete" message whenever I launch it.

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio - Waiting for a required operation to complete. This dialog will close when the operation completes.]

This dialog appears every time I launch Visual Studio and never disappears. As of the writing of this post, Visual Studio has been doing this for a half-hour. This is my fourth attempt at trying to get Visual Studio to start. Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem? I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 2 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: Are you just trying to open VS via a link to it directly, or are you trying to open it by double-clicking a solution?  Have you tried starting it while logged in as a different user? How about while in Safe Mode?  Have you tried repairing/reinstalling VS yet? Have you trying starting VS with the `/log` switch, so you can examine the startup logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the Solution's **.suo** (Solution User Options) file. I'm not exactly sure why the hang-on-launch happens. I assume that some option gets into a weird state, and this forces them all to reset.

[Here's a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96780/why-is-visual-studio-constantly-crashing), where the same conclusion is reached: when .suo files become corrupt 'odd things happen'.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio 2013**

Power failure in which not using UPS , machine loses power -->  3 times now VS 2013 would hang and my solution I found was to DELETE everything in this folder

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
```

However THIS time it is not recovering.

I do have **Visual Studio 2015** and it NEVER happens to VS 2015.

**SOLUTION FOR ME**

1. I opened a different solution in VS 2015 which opens fine
2. I then attempt to open the same solution that will NOT open in VS 2013 IN VS 2013 and it NOW WORKS.

:/  ODD I know.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, VS 2013 Professional was hanging on startup because the license was no longer valid.

Last item in the log file:

```xml
<entry>
    <record>367</record>
    <time>2015/07/13 20:11:05.051</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UserConnection</source>
    <description>myemailaddrs@gmail.com signed in for IDE user</description>
</entry>
```

And on the msdn.microsoft.com subscription page: "Your subscription is no longer active, contact your administrator."

I had to get an updated subscription from my employer.

Comment: Did you have this problem recently? Visual Studio 2015 is slated for release exactly a week from today and upgrades to it will be free if you have a 2013 Community, Professional, Premium, or Ultimate license. I wonder if Microsoft is making some change to the license before releasing. I'm not sure if that is actually the case, I'm just speculating.

Comment: In my case the problem was on my end, due to my employer deactivating our Professional licenses and activating Premium, so all I had to do was install Premium and switch over. **However**, it would have been a lot more helpful if MS had coded VS to tell me that there was an issue with my license instead of just hanging.

Comment: What @KerryRandolph ran into is exactly what happened to me.  Really wish VS would give you a more appropriate response rather than just hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer for the fifth time seems to have solved the problem. I do not know how or why, but it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: lol . Seems that restarting the computer is a universal solution for every problem ;)

Comment: @user11207 At times it does seem that way.

Comment: "60% of the time it works 100% of the time"   ~ anchorman quote

Comment: I'm loving the person that downvoted my answer just because it is generic. I marked it as the answer because it's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run VS in safe mode using the command "devenv /SafeMode"
Open the solution. It won't load every module, just wait for it to complete.
Close VS.
Re-open VS normally and open the solution.
It solved problem for me

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that helped me is updating the package. Open the solution that is having this "waiting for internal operation to complete" then Go to Tools - Nuget Package Manager - Package Manager Console. Then run "Update-Package". After the update, I was able to close and open the solution with no problems. Hope this helps your issues.

Answer (score -1):

Run devenv.exe /ResetSettings from a VS 2013 developer command prompt.

Comment: It worked for me. Experienced the same issue.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for if I experience any more issues, but at this point I am actually using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise instead.

Comment: It would be good to describe the function of devenv.exe and why it should fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but this sounds like a Catch-22 — how do you get to a VS 2013 developer command prompt in the first place if you can't get Visual Studio to start?

Comment: @Stese `devenv.exe` is the main executable for Visual Studio.